# Getting garbage printed

Tags: c, cuda, garbage

I am trying the following simple CUDA C code but getting garbage value printed:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void hellocuda(int* tidx){
   *tidx = 100;
}

int main(){

    int* d_tidx;
    int* c;

    cudaMalloc((void**) &d_tidx, 1);

    c = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

    hellocuda<<<1,1>>>(d_tidx);

    cudaMemcpy(c, d_tidx, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("%d\n", *c);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output I am getting on this is: `-273093020`

Could someone help debugging this code. Thanks.

Comment: One problem i see is that your only allocating 1 byte but an int is 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
printf("%d\n", *c);
```

pulls `sizeof(*c)` bytes from the stack, from which only the first byte is valid memory, as allocated by:

```
int * c;
...
c = (int*) malloc(1);
```

As `sizeof(*c)` definitly is larger then `1` the call to `printf()` above provokes undeinfed behaviuor.

---

Allthough I cannot really parse this:

```
cudaMalloc((void**) &d_tidx, 1);
```

The `1` looks obscure to me.

Comment: Thanks, I changed `cudaMalloc((void**) &d_tidx, 1);` to `cudaMalloc((void**) &d_tidx, sizeof(int));` and it worked.